# How to align gracefully the check box

Tags: html, css

So, here is the snippet of the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/q4ZNc/

Please take a moment to run that code snippet.

WHat I am trying to do is the green box below.. Each checkbox to spread themselves out such that it is able to align with the borders of the box above...

So.. not that text has to spread out...something like:

if currently it is like

```
 <--------------------------Header above-------------------------------------->
   <---c1----><---c2----><----c3-----><----c4--->
```

I want the above to be..

```
 <-------c1-------><------c2------><--------c3---------><-------c4------>[Submit]
```

Sorry I might have messed the spacing. But basically equidistant spacing.

I am newbie.. and have been trying to solve this since past hour and decided to post it here.
Any suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Play around with percentages, like `padding: 25%`.

Comment: @Kolink: Please take a look now.. ?? or did i missed some other crucial info thanks

Comment: Is the width of the checkbox area static or dynamic?

Comment: For now.. static.. But it would be sweet if i add another checkbox and it automatically adjusts itself..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a `div.inputContainer` around each input, center aligned it and set its `width:20%` as there are 5 inputs.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/q4ZNc/1/)

To make it dynamic based on the number of checkboxes, you would need to do a little scripting.  Here is an example using JQuery:

```
var inputContainers = $('.inputContainer');
inputContainerLength = inputContainers.length;
inputContainers.width(100 / inputContainerLength + '%');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/q4ZNc/4/)

Comment: Very nice elegant solution. I would also add .checkbox{margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;} to make the whole thing look less squashed.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your input display as `table-cell`, wrap them all in a div that is rendered as `table-row`, and put `display-table` and 100% width on the container (`.checklist`).

This will force the browser to evenly distribute cells

[See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy8Z9/)